# How do I add multiple instances to aws_network_interface_sg_attachment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, elastic-network-interface

I have the following code and would like to attach a security group to an Elastic Network Interface (ENI).

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # us-west-2
  count = var.instances
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name
  subnet_id  = aws_subnet.tf_test_subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [ aws_security_group.allow_tls.id ]
}
```

```
resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = aws_security_group.allow_tls.id
  network_interface_id = element(aws_instance.foo.*.primary_network_interface_id,0)
}
```

however upon deployment of the code I get

```
Error: security group sg-060153b203cbaa6d5 already attached to interface ID eni-006293e38b0056a91
```

I suspect that this may be because of the ,0 index value but I'm not sure?

so the question is how can I iterate over the instances and apply the security group to the ENI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is actually trying to attach it twice:

- Once as part of the `aws_instance resource`’s `vpc_security_group_ids` attribute,
- and then again using the `aws_network_interface_sg_attachment`.

In your case, you don’t need the `aws_network_interface_sg_attachment` resource.

Comment: ah ok, thank you for that, I didn't realize they were the same

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing. The separate attachment resource can be helpful if you’d otherwise have circular dependencies, which isn’t the case here.

Comment: just ran a ```terraform apply``` on the code without ```aws_network_interface_sg_attachment``` component worked like a charm, thanks agian

Comment: Sure, glad I could help